# C++: What is wrong with this while loop?

Tags: c++

Here is the relevant problematic code with comments

```
     // right now hack=1 & i=4(both integers)
while(hack<i)  //loop begins
    {
        hack++;
        Linklist<node*> z=advancer(l); 
      //Linklist is my own class, node is my own object type
      //l(type same as z) is predefined before the loop, and advancer is a function.
      //Interestingly, l=advancer(l) doesnt work directly so i introduce z 
      //which i do not understand why.
        l=z;
        cout<<"print" //just to confirm code reaches here, Yes it does
    }
//while loop doesnt execute again,checked by a cout statement in beginning.
```

So if the while loop is reaching till its last line, why is not executing again? C++ amazes me at times but this is the most amazing thing i have ever seen, and i m clueless because this is so basic code that there doesn't seem any scope inside to be wrong. Please help. All kinds of possible error sources would be appreciated.

My actual program is too large(1000 lines) so i m not bothering giving background of other functions as i think its not relevant. I would love to elaborate if someone here things it might be a cause and is willing to listen :)

One possible thing i could figure out is probably the function was being computed so it executed the cout in the meantime, but thats just a guess.

Comment: @khajvah, i tried . but doesnt work. any reason why you think it should?

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the loop! You will see what happens to hack and i.

Comment: send me the whole code or sscce, i want test it : P

Comment: Maybe `hack` or `i` are globals and `advancer()` modifies one of them.

Comment: *"I'm not bothering [...] as I think its not relevant"* - your bug is a result of this.

Comment: there is no way for anyone to **know** what your problem is based on the code that you provided. I can promise you that `while` loop behaves correcly - it's been tested thoroughly by many programmers. It's something that you've done to the condition given to the `while`. I'm voting to close based on not giving a short selfcontained compilable program showing the issue.

Comment: @gabrielnegut, Nope, i put up a cout at the end of the loop to check they were not modified. And my function doesn't do anything to that part. This is exactly what disappoints me.

Comment: @Default, i m pretty certain the condition given to while is alright. I think my call to some function is stuck up somewhere which causes this. I do not understand the source of the problem and so cannot produce an SSCCE though i agree that would have been helpful .

Comment: @AkashRupela: Not understanding the source of the problem shouldn't prevent you producing an SSCCE. You simply start throwing away bits of your program that you think aren't related to the bug ("think", not "know"; it's OK to guess) until you either reach a fairly minimal program that exhibits the bug, or the bug suddenly evaporates. Either way, you'll have made significant progress towards resolving your problem, and you might even find that you've answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing something bad somewhere else in a place that is not shown.

In C++ when you make a mistake it's not guaranteed that an error will pop up immediately and what may happen (and often happens) is that code apparently keeps working but in another place where instead the code is correct the behaviour seems crazy.

`while` works and you should try to carve this into your brain as soon as possible because otherwise it will be impossible for you to get any far in programming.

More than this... the compiler works, the libraries work, then OS works, the RAM is ok. The bug is just in YOUR code. This is the only mindset that allows progressing.

Sometimes, very rarely, you can find a bug in a compiler or in a widely used library, but you're entitled to claim a bug in someone else's code **ONLY** if you can find EXACTLY what the error is and you can produce an example where the error clearly happens.

The nice book "[The Pragmatic Programmer](http://www.google.it/?q=the%20pragmatic%20programmer)" has a chapter on this dangerous mindset that can really destroy your possibilities to advance... and is titled "`select` isn't broken".

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. That certainly gives me a lot of direction to work upon and not take things negatively, and stay focussed on finding the bug and not calling 'grapes are sour' . :)

Comment: [`select` isn't broken](http://pragmatictips.com/26): *"If you see hoof prints, think horses - not zebras."* Also consider: [The First Rule of Programming: It's Always Your Fault](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html)

Comment: @IInspectable: thanks for the correction, fixed. I've taken my copy to the office for other colleagues to read and I didn't check online (in case you're wondering AFAIK none of them picked it up :-( )